# Setting remote ip and port in littleproxy

Tags: java, proxy, little-proxy

In littleProxy, how can I set the remote ip and port?
The sample in their website :

```
HttpProxyServer server =
    DefaultHttpProxyServer.bootstrap()
        .withPort(8080)
        .start();
```

only sets the local port.

Comment: What do you mean by "remote IP and port" ? Do you want to configure a chained proxy ? Question seems a bit unclear...

Comment: @Guillaume, I think he's asking how to define the target server's IP and port

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27039042/in-littleproxy-how-to-set-proxy-ip-and-port

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The request target must be in absolute-form, as specified by RFC 7230, section 5.3.2, to be forwarded by LittleProxy. The following code works in LittleProxy v1.1.0beta1:

```
Pattern REQUEST_TARGET_ORIGIN_FORM_PREFIX = Pattern.compile("/[^/]");

@Override
public HttpResponse clientToProxyRequest(HttpObject httpObject) {
  if (httpObject instanceof HttpRequest) {
    HttpRequest httpRequest = (HttpRequest) httpObject;
    if (REQUEST_TARGET_ORIGIN_FORM_PREFIX.matcher(httpRequest.getUri()).lookingAt()) {
      String uriRemote = "http://myRemoteHost:myRemotePort" + httpRequest.getUri();
      httpRequest.setUri(uriRemote);
    }
  }
  return null;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The remote IP and port are retrieved from the "Host" field in the request sent to LittleProxy.

e.g. A request with the header below:

```
POST http://x.x.x.x:1234 HTTP/1.1
Authorization: Basic cjknkcjenkjljvbt==
Host: x.x.x.x:1234
Accept: */*
Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive
User-Agent: MyNode/test
Content-Type: text/xml
Content-Length: 1079
Expect: 100-continue
```

would be forwarded by LittleProxy to remote host x.x.x.x,  port 1234. Knowing this, one way to ensure that your requests are channeled through the Proxy to the right remote host/port is to modify the requests being sent by your client application

Alternatively,  use LittleProxy filters to edit the request header; change it to your desired remote IP/port

```
HttpProxyServer server =
    DefaultHttpProxyServer.bootstrap()
        .withPort(8080)
        .withFiltersSource(new HttpFiltersSourceAdapter() {
            public HttpFilters filterRequest(HttpRequest originalRequest, ChannelHandlerContext ctx) {
               return new HttpFiltersAdapter(originalRequest) {
                  @Override
                  public HttpResponse clientToProxyRequest(HttpObject httpObject) {
                      // Modify header, replace remote IP/Port
                      return null;
                  }

                  @Override
                  public HttpResponse proxyToServerRequest(HttpObject httpObject) {
                      // TODO: implement your filtering here
                      return null;
                  }

                  @Override
                  public HttpObject serverToProxyResponse(HttpObject httpObject) {
                      // TODO: implement your filtering here
                      return httpObject;
                  }

                  @Override
                  public HttpObject proxyToClientResponse(HttpObject httpObject) {
                      // TODO: implement your filtering here
                      return httpObject;
                  }   
               };
            }
        })
        .start();
```

I've had success with the first approach (modifying requests from clients)