# In LittleProxy, how to set proxy ip and port

Tags: java, netty, nio, little-proxy

In LittleProxy, how to set proxy ip and port? The sample in their website :

**HttpProxyServer server =
    DefaultHttpProxyServer.bootstrap()
        .withPort(8080)
        .start();**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the source code you should be able to do something like

```
HttpProxyServer server = DefaultHttpProxyServer.bootstrap()
  .withAddress(new InetSocketAddress("127.0.0.1", 8080)).start();
```

Comment: I want to forward the messgae(request) to a real proxy server, Can littleproxy do this? if can, where to set the host and port of a real proxy server? thanks.

Comment: I think you need bootstrap().withChainProxyManager(chainProxyManager). Implement ChainedProxyManager to return a list of ChainedProxy implementations. You possibly only need to extend ChainedProxyAdapter and override getChainedProxyAddress. Sorry I can't be more specific as I've not tried it myself.

Answer (score 2):

This is a tested code derived using the comment of [johnstlr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1033622/johnstlr).

```
ChainedProxyAdapter adapter = new ChainedProxyAdapter() {
    @Override
    public InetSocketAddress getChainedProxyAddress() {
        return new InetSocketAddress("your.proxy.address", 1234);
    }
};
ChainedProxyManager manager = new ChainedProxyManager() {
    @Override
    public void lookupChainedProxies(HttpRequest httpRequest, Queue<ChainedProxy> chainedProxies) {
        chainedProxies.add(adapter);
    }
};

HttpProxyServer server = DefaultHttpProxyServer.bootstrap().withChainProxyManager(manager).withPort(8080).start();
```